# Swift 3 - Push a new view but keep the same NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, navigationcontroller

I have a `UISearchBar` in my application. When I press a button to "open" the searchbar does a new view appear. But the problem is that the `NavigationController` changes and the `UISearchBar` disappear. How can I do so I can keep the current `NavigationController` with my searchbar even if a new view appear. (So I still searching when the new view appear)

P.s my code is not the best and I´m not using Storyboard!

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UISearchBarDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    setupNavigationBar() 
}
```

Here is the new view that appear:

```
class UserSearchController: UICollectionViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue


    }

}
```

And here is the whole searchbar code:

```
import UIKit

var searchBar = UISearchBar()
var searchBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem?
var logoImageView: UIImageView!

extension HomeController {

    func setupNavigationBar() {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "search"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showSearchBar), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton

        let logoImage = UIImage(named: "home")!
        logoImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: logoImage.size.width, height: logoImage.size.height))
        logoImageView.image = logoImage
        navigationItem.titleView = logoImageView


        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.minimal
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.gray
        searchBarButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem

    }


    func showSearchBar() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let userSearchController = UserSearchController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(userSearchController, animated: true)
        searchBar.alpha = 0
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
        navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(nil, animated: true)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.searchBar.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        })
    }


    public func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        hideSearchBar()

    }

    func hideSearchBar() {
        navigationItem.setRightBarButton(searchBarButtonItem, animated: true)
        logoImageView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.navigationItem.titleView = self.logoImageView
            self.logoImageView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: { finished in

        })
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your search bar is only visible on your first View Controller is because you are using the View Controller's `titleView` property. Each UIViewController has it's own `titleView` property, so if you push a View Controller onto your first VC, it will also need to have the titleView property set to a search bar view with the required configuration.

Comment: Note that in iOS 11 this will change.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. But I´m not super good att Swift yet and I have tried search around a little bit. I still don´t really know how I should do it to fix my problem... Hope you could help me a little bit more. And thanks Matt for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a base class, add UISearchBar above the base class, and then you want the current controller with UISearchBar to inherit your base class

Comment: Could you help me a little bit more with your answer? As I mentioned above I´m I not so good at Swift. Thanks!